# laravelでバリデーション全体の停止を任意のフィールドに対して指定したい

Tags: laravel

laravelのバリデーションなのですが、他のフィールドのバリデーションに影響与える重要なフィールドをまず最初に行い、もしだめならバリデーション全体を停止したいとします。

仮にその重要なフィールドをAとするとAが正しいという前提でB、Cなどのフィールドをカスタムバリデーションしたりしています。

laravelでバリデーションを途中停止させる方法には`bail`と`stopOnFirstFailure`の二つがありますが、`bail`は、そのフィールドは停止しても次のフィールドでバリデーションを続けてしまい、`stopOnFirstFailure`は全体停止しますが、フィールド指定ができずどのフィールドでも停止してしまいます。

欲しいのは`bail`のように各フィールドに指定できて、`stopOnFirstFailure`のように全体停止するものなのですが、こういったことを行う方法はないでしょうか。

現在自分が行っている対策として、フォームリクエスト内のrules()でわざわざValidator::make()を行ってルール追加を制御するということをやっているのですが、見苦しく保守性が悪いので何かシンプルな方法があればコードが綺麗になって助かります。

Answer (score 1):

今のところ標準機能としては存在しないので，ベタ書きよりもマシになるように，自分で拡張して DRY 性を高めるぐらいの工夫しかできないと思います。

```php
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as BaseValidator;

class Validator extends BaseValidator
{
    /**
     * @var bool|string[]
     */
    protected $stopOnFirstFailure = false;

    /**
     * @param  bool|string[] $stopOnFirstFailure
     * @return $this
     */
    public function stopOnFirstFailure($stopOnFirstFailure = true)
    {
        $this->stopOnFirstFailure = $stopOnFirstFailure;

        return $this;
    }

    public function passes(): bool
    {
        $this->messages = new MessageBag;

        [$this->distinctValues, $this->failedRules] = [[], []];

        // We'll spin through each rule, validating the attributes attached to that
        // rule. Any error messages will be added to the containers with each of
        // the other error messages, returning true if we don't have messages.
        foreach ($this->rules as $attribute => $rules) {
            if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                continue;
            }

            // ↓ここを改造
            if ($this->messages->isNotEmpty() && $this->determineStopOnFisrtFailure($attribute)) {
                break;
            }

            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                $this->validateAttribute($attribute, $rule);

                if ($this->shouldBeExcluded($attribute)) {
                    $this->removeAttribute($attribute);

                    break;
                }

                if ($this->shouldStopValidating($attribute)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Here we will spin through all of the "after" hooks on this validator and
        // fire them off. This gives the callbacks a chance to perform all kinds
        // of other validation that needs to get wrapped up in this operation.
        foreach ($this->after as $after) {
            $after();
        }

        return $this->messages->isEmpty();
    }

    protected function determineStopOnFisrtFailure(string $attribute): bool
    {
        if (is_array($this->stopOnFirstFailure) && in_array($attribute, $this->stopOnFirstFailure, true)) {
            return true;
        }

        return (bool)$this->stopOnFirstFailure;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Factory $factory): void
    {
        $factory->resolver(fn (...$args) => new Validator(...$args));
    }
}
```

これをサービスプロバイダに登録すれば，自分で用意した拡張 Validator クラスが使用されるので，`stopOnFirstFailure` の対象に `string[]` を指定することができるようになるでしょう。

Comment: この機能，とくに大きく後方互換性が壊れることも無さそうなので，プルリクエストを Laravel 9.x に向けて出してみてはどうでしょうか？採用されそうな気もします